# VSTS CI for XCode build for app with watch kit extension

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, xcodebuild, watchos

I have automated build on VSTS for my iOS app which is working well except when I add watch kit extension, the build breaks with this error:

target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.watchkit2-extension', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform.

The watch kit target specifies the BaseSDK and supported platform as 'WatchOS'. When I build from XCode on my mac the build succeeds. Its only on VSTS it is failing.

How do I specify multiple values for $(SDK) variable in VSTS. or rather how do I set up xcode build task in VSTS so that it uses the platform specified in the target definition rather than the variable value for $(SDK)

Updated to add screenshots:

Also, the watchkit extension target is added as a dependency for the iOS app target. the scheme I am using lists the dependency as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show the detail build tasks you are using and the detail build logs?

Comment: edited post to include screenshots. not sure if i have added all what you are looking for. please let me know if you need more info. thanks!

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT, do you see anything that I am missing? any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: Never mind. This one is resolved. The fix is to not set the value of SDK as $(SDK) in the build task. It should be left blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to not set the value of SDK as $(SDK) in the build task. It should be left blank.